# Bootstrap menu for mobile not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this fixed top menu that is working properly with desktop  but with mobile this is not working how to make this to work with mobile.

My code is as below.
I am using `bootstrap-3.6` and `font-awesome`.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="Brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id="f-request-count"></span>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <span id="info-count"></span>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="get-info-list">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="infolist" role="menu">
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">User Name <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="userddlist" role="menu">
            <li><a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search-pd">
        <form action="Search" class="form-inline ">
          <input class="form-control srch" id="search-header" type="search" name="name" />
          <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the mobile button markup.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

You need to make the `data-target` value same with your `navbar` id.

complete code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Brand">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span id="f-request-count"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <span id="info-count"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="get-info-list">
                            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="infolist" role="menu"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">User Name <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="userddlist" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="Profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="search-pd">
                    <form action="Search" class="form-inline ">
                        <input class="form-control srch" id="search-header" type="search" name="name" />
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can I change content dynamically if device is mobile like <a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> insted of this can i show Home  etc.

Comment: Did you wanted to remove the text from a tag on mobile ?

Comment: Like it is showing only home image insted of this on mobile it should show home image and `Home`.

Comment: Yes you can use Responsive utilities Classes like this
`<a href="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"><span class="visible-xs-inline">Home</span></i></a>`